# Understand Law of Total Probability

Tags: probability

Having

$$\ln p(y) = \ln \frac{p(y, \theta)}{p(\theta, y)}$$

which is a result of the [product rule](http://ais.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/teaching/ss10/robotics/etc/probability-rules.pdf)

I do not understand [here (slide 17)](http://people.inf.ethz.ch/bkay/talks/Brodersen_2013_03_22.pdf)

$$ \ln p(y) = \int q(\theta) \ln \frac{p(y, \theta)}{p(\theta, y)} d\theta  $$

It seems like they are trying to marginalize out the $\theta$ but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be clearer to write it like this:

$$\log p(y) = 1 \times \log \frac{p(y,\theta)}{p(\theta|y)} = \int q(\theta) d\theta \times \log \frac{p(y,\theta)}{p(\theta|y)} $$

And then you can move the thing on the right inside of the integral since it isn't a function of $\theta$